# Use jQuery to turn cell values under specific th into links

Tags: jquery

I need to use jquery to loop through the following table and turn the cell values under the "Account Name" th into hyperlinks

```
 <table id="exampleTable">
     <tr>
         <th>Type</th>
         <th>Account Name</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td>Type 1</td>
          <td>Account Name 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td>Type 2</td>
          <td>Account Name 2</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

I know I need to loop through the table rows and somehow only target the cells under the Account Name heading with code that looks something like this:

```
 var searchTerm = $('td').text();

 $("td").append(" <a href='http://example.com? 
 securityGroup="+ $.trim(searchTerm) +"'>" + searchTerm + "</a>");
```

But I have know idea how to target the specific cells under the Account Name th using a loop. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Get index of `th` and use it to target only index element of each `tr`. then simply use `td` and use `html` function instead of `append`

Comment: What should a cell like `<td>Account Name 1</td>` look like HTML-wise afterwards?

Comment: @MatthewTuman Does "rearrange columns" means that the heading "Account Name" might be in the 1st column instead of the 2nd column?

Comment: @matthias_h yes exactly

Comment: @MatthewTuman Thanks for clearing this, I've adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this: loop over all `<tr>`, get the 2nd `<td>` (the first row with  elements will be omitted) and create the hyperlink accordingly (if the value in the cell already contains the protocol, the adding of "http://" can be removed):

```js
$("tr").each(function() {
  let link = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
  let anchor = "<a href='http://" + link + "'>" + link + "</a>";
  $(this).find("td:eq(1)").html(anchor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table id="exampleTable">
   <tr>
     <th>Type</th>
     <th>Account Name</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Type 1</td>
     <td>Account Name 1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Type 2</td>
     <td>Account Name 2</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Update: As explained in the comments at the answer, the column in which the links are located could be changed by the user as the columns could be changed. In order to get the  cell with the heading "Account Cell" to get the correct column, following changes are necessary:

```js
let title;
$("th").each(function() {
  if ($.trim($(this).text()) == "Account Name") {
    title = $(this).index();
  }
});
$("tr").each(function() {
  let link = $.trim($(this).find("td:eq(" + title + ")").text());
  let anchor = "<a href='http://" + link + "'>" + link + "</a>";
  $(this).find("td:eq(" + title + ")").html(anchor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table id="exampleTable">
     <tr>
         <th>Type</th>
         <th>Account Name</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td>Type 1</td>
          <td>Account Name 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td>Type 2</td>
          <td>Account Name 2</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```